# WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: Course

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am working with Rails and I cannot seem to get past this error. A course has many notes and a note belongs to course.

The error I get is:

> Can't mass-assign protected attributes: `course`

Here is my `course.rb`

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :semester
has_many :notes, :dependent => :destroy

attr_accessible :course_name, :course_number, :instructor, :instructor_email, :class_meets, 
                :class_starts, :semester_id
end
```

`note.rb`

```
class Note < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :course
attr_accessor :course_name, :course_id
attr_accessible :title, :date, :body, :extra, :course_name, :course_id 
end
```

`notes/_form.html.erb` (User can select a course and create notes)

```
<%= f.select("course", Course.find(:all).collect {|c| [c.course_name, c.id]})%>
```

Is there anyway to resolve this error?

Comment: Have a look at http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

Comment: The error is pretty self-explanatory, you're missing `:course` from your `attr_accessible`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to add

`attr_accessible :course`

inside your `Note.rb`

Comment: Now i get *Course() expected, got String()*

Comment: Where abouts are you getting that error? (what line of code and copy/paste the code)

Comment: I get the error in notes_controller '@semester =Semester.new(params[:semester])'

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using rails version which is less than rails 4 you have to explicitly pass the parameters which you want to access. This is for security reason. However if you use rails 4 by default rails will handle this for you. Its called strong parameters.

So you've to tell to your model that let my controller and view access this attributes.

```
  attr_accessible :course
```